# how to move a file(image) from users android device to the database?

Tags: php, android

I just want to know how can I make the user to browse the image and then save it to the database for example i want to store the user profile picture in some android application. I am using php as the server side language.

Comment: you want to get image from camera?

Comment: Nope. he can browse the image from the galary or file explorer.